# Try-Except ErrorCatching

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, user-input

I'm trying to force the user to input a number using try-except in python however it seems to have no effect.

```
while count>0:
    count=count - 1
    while (length != 8):
        GTIN=input("Please enter a product code ")
        length= len(str(GTIN))
        if length!= 8:
            print("That is not an eight digit number")
            count=count + 1
         while valid == False:
            try:
                GTIN/5
                valid = True
            except ValueError:
                 print("That is an invalid number")
                 count=count + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if the user inputs for example a string, `"hello"/5` yields a `TypeError`, not a `ValueError`, so catch that instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make the input value an int `int(value)`, which raises `ValueError` if it cannot be converted.

Here's a function that should do what you want with some comments:

```
def get_product_code():
    value = ""
    while True:  # this will be escaped by the return
        # get input from user and strip any extra whitespace: " input  "
        value = raw_input("Please enter a product code ").strip()
        #if not value:            # escape from input if nothing is entered
        #    return None
        try:
            int(value)           # test if value is a number
        except ValueError:       # raised if cannot convert to an int
            print("Input value is not a number")
            value = ""
        else:                    # an Exception was not raised
            if len(value) == 8:  # looks like a valid product code!
                return value
            else:
                print("Input is not an eight digit number")
```

Once defined, call the function to get input from the user

```
product_code = get_product_code()
```

You should also be sure to except and handle `KeyboardInterrupt` anytime you're expecting user input, because they may put in `^C` or something else to crash your program.

```
product code = None  # prevent reference before assignment bugs
try:
    product_code = get_product_code()  # get code from the user
except KeyboardInterrupt:  # catch user attempts to quit
    print("^C\nInterrupted by user")

if product_code:
    pass  # do whatever you want with your product code
else:
    print("no product code available!")
    # perhaps exit here
```

Comment: How would you call this?

Comment: Once defined, the same way you would call any other function. [Here's a fairly good explanation of that process and usage](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: Ahhh,I see now,however I want to use this within the code,not in the shell.I will see if I can adapt this to my needs,thank you

Comment: Anytime! This should work both within the shell and a script file. If this or another answer on SO solves a question you ask, please do mark it as the answer.